# Cannot convert value of type 'NSUUID?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I want to use `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` method from `CBCentralManager`.
While scanning I printed the identifiers of each peripheral. The one I'm looking for is this:

```
7E34D617-731F-616E-8C89-5729870CDD5E
```

I connected to this peripheral and then I connection callback I tried to do the following:

```
let peripherals = centralManager?.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [NSUUID(uuidString:"7E34D617-731F-616E-8C89-5729870CDD5E")])
print("peripherals = ", peripherals)
```

But I keep getting compilation error stating:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSUUID?' to expected element type 'Array<UUID>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'UUID')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First of all why use NSUUID instead of UUID and secondly it looks like the method doesn’t accept an optional variable so you need to unwrap it.

Comment: `NSUUID.init?(uuidString string: String)`, it can fail if UUID is not valid. So use `flatMap()`. That'd be the first fix, but in fact, prefer `UUID` over `NSUUID`, and the init can't fail.

Comment: There is a `CBUUID` type that is used with the `CoreBluetooth` framework. You might try that